# + compareTo(wordtoCompare : Word) : Integer Java

Tags: java, class, uml, compareto

Currently I am working on a project in which I have to use this UML diagram to create and additional class I understand everything but I am baffled by the last line.

```
compareTo(wordToCompare : Word) : Integer
```

Since Word is the name of the class how would I insert an argument? I tried inputting an Object as an argument but it says:

> Object is an incompatible type with Word.

I researched if Word was a non primitive data-type but could not find any information. I am rather inexperienced and quite confused if anyone could lend some assistance I would be greatly appreciative.

```
Word class UML
-wordCharacters : String
-count : integer
+ CONSTRUCTOR (word : String) 
+ getWord() : String 
+ getCount() : Integer 
+ incrementCount() : void 
+ toString() : String 
+ equals(wordtoCompare : Object) : Boolean 
+ compareTo(wordtoCompare : Word) : Integer

@Override
public boolean equals(Object wordtoCompare) {
    boolean flag = false;
    String currentWord = wordtoCompare.getClass().getName();

    this.compareTo(wordtoCompare);

    return flag;
}

public Integer compareTo(Word wordtoCompare) {

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you post the code of `compareTo`?

Comment: I don't see how you're limited by the parameter type being the same class. Can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: Sure, the return type is `Integer`, not `int`? Because it looks like your `Word` class should implement `Comparable<Word>`.

Comment: That's not going to work, or at least probably not the way you're expecting or wanting it to. Don't you want to be comparing the `wordCharacters` of each instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are overriding the equals method and it should look a bit like this.
You need to check if the `Object` `wordtoCompare` is of the type `Word` or if it´s the current object. After you did check if it´s a type or subtype of `Word` you can cast the `wordtoCompare` to an actuall `Word` object and do your stuff with it.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object wordtoCompare) {
    boolean flag = false;
    if(wordtoCompare == this) return true;
    if(!(wordtoCompare instanceof Word)) return false;
    Word word = (Word)wordtoCompare;

    this.compareTo(word);
    // Whatever you do with your flag
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: I am such a noob lol I just forgot I could use this to signify the class I am in thank-you Kevin for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

You can just create the compareTo Method having a Word parameter. (Word is the class you're currently creating)

```
public class Word{
    ....

    public int compareTo(Word wordToCompare){
        int result = 0;
        //do your compare stuff
        return result;
    }

}
```

If this isn't your problem, I may did not understand the problem properly

Edit:

Your `equals` Method looks the following:

```
public boolean equals(Object wordtoCompare) {
    boolean flag = false;
    String currentWord = wordtoCompare.getClass().getName();

    this.compareTo(wordtoCompare);

    return flag;
}
```

But you have to make sure, that the Object you're working with is really a Word.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object wordtoCompare) {
    boolean flag = false;
    if(wordtoCompare == this) return true;
    if(!(wordtoCompare instanceof Word)) return false;
    Word word = (Word)wordtoCompare;

    int compareResult = this.compareTo(wordtoCompare);
    // Whatever you do with your flag
    return flag;
}
```

This method is taken from Kevin Esche, as he implemented this method properly. Thank you.

And then you have to implement `compareTo` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this I guess

```
class Word{
    String wordCharacters;
    int count;
    public Word(String word){
     ...


   }

.. other stuff

public int compareTo(Word other){
   return wordCharacters.compareTo(other.wordCaracters)
}

}
```